# Dos Batches: write to files without a line ending

Tags: batch-file, newline, dos, text-files

I have a situation while writing a dos batchs script.  A tool I am using to calculate CRC (checksum) of a text string requires the text to be in a file.  The data I am trying to get the CRC for is a filename, but when using a batch to put this filename into a text file to calculate CRC, the batch script naturally puts the line ending (CR/LF) and a blank line at the end.  As this causes the CRC to be wrong, it is a problem.

Is there any way to get a batch script to write to a text file without appending a line ending?  IE to output a single line unfinished to file?

-K.Barad

Comment: does the tool accept an input from the command line, or can you invoke it with a pipe `|`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`<nul set /p ".=text" > file`

It's faster and safer than `echo.|set /P ="text" > file`

The nul redirection is faster than a pipe with `echo.` (btw `echo.`can fail).
The style of the quotes allowes to output also quotes.

But there are always restrictions!
Vista and Win7 have a "feature" to supress leading spaces, Tabs and CR's.
Xp can output text with leading spaces and so.
And it's not possible to begin the output text with an equal sign (results in a syntax error)

Comment: When I run `<nul set /p ".=text" > file` it hangs my terminal. What's going on?

Comment: Why do I get `The syntax of the command is incorrect.` when I try it?..

Answer (score 5):

You could

```
echo.|set /P ="text" > file
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479734/echo-with-no-new-line-cr-lf)

Or directly pipe the text to the command line:
echo "text" | checksum_program.exe

**edit**:

if you're using [CRC32DOS](http://www.erikburd.org/projects/crc32/CRC32Dos.html), then you can use its command line option `-c` to ignore `CR`s.

Comment: unfortunately it's a custom CRC program.  Thanks for the tip though, file appending without new lines is a useful technique.